# MYSQL query average price

Tags: mysql

I have to calculate the average price of a house in Groningen. 
Though the price is not stored as an number but as a string (with some additional information) and it uses a point ('.') as a thousands separator. 
Price is stored as 'Vraagprijs' in Dutch.

The table results are:

```
&euro; 95.000 k.k.

&euro; 116.500 v.o.n.

&euro; 115.000 v.o.n.
```

and goes so on...

My query:

```
'$'SELECT AVG(SUBSTRING(value,8,8)) AS AveragePrice_Groningen 
  FROM properties 
  WHERE name = 'vraagprijs' 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
  FROM estate 
  WHERE pc_wp LIKE '%Groningen%' 
  AND properties.woid = estate.id);
```

The result is: 
209.47509187620884 
But it has to be:

20947509187620,884

How can i get this done?

Comment: Wow. House prices in Groningen are even higher than London!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CAST DECIMAL and SPLIT for get the right part of the string

```
 '$'
SELECT AVG( CAST(SPLIT_STR(value,' ', 2)) AS DECIMAL) AS AveragePrice_Groningen 
FROM properties 
WHERE name = 'vraagprijs' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM estate 
WHERE pc_wp LIKE '%Groningen%' 
AND properties.woid = estate.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **AVG(SUBSTRING(value,8,8))** dosent work:

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT *,SUBSTRING(`value`,8,8), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, ' ', -2),' ',1) FROM properties;
+----+-----------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | value                 | SUBSTRING(`value`,8,8) | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, ' ', -2),' ',1) |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | &euro; 95.000 k.k.    | 95.000 k               | 95.000                                                   |
|  2 | &euro; 116.500 v.o.n. | 116.500                | 116.500                                                  |
|  3 | &euro; 115.000 v.o.n. | 115.000                | 115.000                                                  |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

**change it to **

```
AVG(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, ' ', -2),' ',1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You entered the data with the `.` as decimal separator, which is normal in Dutch, but not normal in English where they tend to use the `,` as decimal separator.

Enter the data into you database as 215000.000, etc and you should get normal values as answer.

Comment: Yeah but i received the database this way.